# Is breeze provide support to work with c# Enums

Tags: enums, breeze

I want to populate my dropdowns with enum using breeze. It show enum in breeze metadata but I did not find a way how to consume it. Is breeze provide support yet to work c# enums?

Comment: Are you using Breeze.js or Breeze.sharp?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a standard Breeze WebApi server then enum values should all be coming down as strings and can be saved back to the server also as strings.  Out of the box, the default Breeze WebApi server implementation will convert the strings to the correct enum values automatically in both directions.

(Note: this will not work with a server using the current MS WebApi/OData provider because MS does not yet not support enums with this provider - MS will support this in their upcoming 4.0 release.)

So, for example, assuming that you had a server side enum that looked like this:

```
public enum RoleType {
   Guest = 0,
   Restricted = 1,
   Standard = 2,
   Admin = 3
}
```

in conjunction with a 'Role' class that had a 'RoleType' property, then the the following query would work:

```
    var query = new EntityQuery("Roles").where("RoleType", "==", 'Restricted');
    myEntityManager.executeQuery(query).then(...);
```

Similarly, if you wanted to change a RoleType for a given role then you could

```
    role.RoleType = "Standard"; // assuming breeze backingStore adapter.
    myEntityManager.saveChanges();
```

Comment: Thanks for the briefed answer. However, I am wondering if I access enums to populate dropdown with it on client side. How it would be possible? please suggest

Answer (score 0):

If you are generating offline breeze metadata then you can get all Enums definition in metadata itself and you can create a JS Dictionary(associated array) to populate all enum types and their definitions.

Well My situation was that I was using NancyFx(No EF) + Breeze + AngularJS for my web project. I generated metadata offline and stored it in a metadata.js file.

After creating EntityManager, I extracted enum defintions in a JS dictionary which I used later for binding dropdown, display corresponding enum strings etc.

**Extract Enum Definition & Store in JS Dictionary**

```
        JSON.parse(window.app.metadata).schema.enumType.forEach(function (enumType) {
            var newEnumValues = [];

            enumType.member.forEach(function (enumValue) {
                var newEnumValue = { id: enumValue.value, name: enumValue.name };
                newEnumValues.push(newEnumValue);
            });

            enumDictionary[enumType.name] = newEnumValues;
        });
```

**Method to retrieve enum value on base of enum name and valueid**

```
        function GetEnumDictionaryValue(enumName, enumValueId) {
            var result = null;
            enumDictionary[enumName].some(function (enumValue) {
                if (enumValue.id == enumValueId) {
                    result = enumValue.name;
                    return;
                }
            });

            return result;
        }
```

**Binding Values to Dropdown**
Now for binding dropdowns, just call  enumDictionary[] and store result in a controller variable.
I was using Angular JS, so I used below code on html page

```
      <select ng-options="type.id as type.name for type in <VariableName>"
                        ></select>
```